# asp.net webforms + jquery = can't get button press

Tags: asp.net, jquery, forms, submit

wanted to include jquery in masterpage, but as soon as I did that - my login page stopped working... in chrome console I'm getting:

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onsubmit' of null
```

from stack I can see that it is here:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager1', document.getElementById('aspnetForm'));
```

in firefox:

```
this._form is null
this._onsubmit = this._form.onsubmit;
```

and that error is in ScriptResource.axd?=...

and this causes that I can't just click on the Login button - it does nothing... on the other hand - everything works in Opera... even better - if I am to remove:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

then everything works fine (tried also other versions of jquery)... now the best is that other pages - that also have buttons and events, work... I've even changed the login page not to use Login control... and it still doesn't work... I'm really confused right now...

Comment: please provide here the order of loading your scripts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My colleague found a solution by an accident... if you change:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it magically starts to work... now... this should be xhtml... can anyone explain to me WHY there is a difference here?!

Comment: Script tags should never be used in the self-closing way. You can find more info on why here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work